# Assign a Value for data attribute

Tags: jquery

How to assign a value to the data attribute ?

I have tried is as below.But not work.

**JS**

```
 $(btn).closest('tr').find('td:first').data('price-service-key') = petKey + '-' + editedPrice + '-' + serviceKey;
```

**HTML**

```
 <td data-extra-key="<%: item.ServiceKey %>" data-pet-key="<%: item.PetKey %>" data-price-service-key="<%: item.PetKey +'-'+item.Price.ToString("0.00")+'-'+ item.ServiceKey %>">
                <%: item.ServiceName %>
                for
                <%: item.PetName %><sub><%: item.Description %></sub>
            </td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `.data()` as a getter, as a setter it accepts 2 arguments:

```
$(btn).closest('tr')
      .find('td:first')
      .data('price-service-key', petKey+'-'+editedPrice+'-'+serviceKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage is

```
$(btn).closest('tr').find('td:first').data('price-service-key', petKey + '-' + editedPrice + '-' + serviceKey);
```

Comment: No, `.prop()` doesn't work here, `data-*` attributes are stored in the `dataset` property of the element, `prop('dataset')` returns `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an attribute:

```
.attr('data-price-service-key', '....')
```